# Why am I getting null instead of http response body?

Tags: post, null

I send a POST request to the discord api, but I get null instead of the expected data

Here's my php code:

```
public function login($payload): array{
        $ch = curl_init("https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/login");
        $payload_s  =  json_encode($payload);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload_s);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload_s),
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.66',
                'Accept: application/json'
            )
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result        =  curl_exec($ch);
        $headers_size  =  curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

        curl_close($ch);

        $body      =  substr($result, $headers_size);
        $response  =  json_decode($body);

        return json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
    }
```

Instead of getting a similar set of data from body:

```
    "user_id": "683686211423830106",
    "mfa": true,
    "sms": false,
    "ticket": "ticket",
    "backup": true,
    "totp": true,
    "webauthn": null
}
```

I'm getting a null

Comment: Can you add an example of what `$payload` looks like?